# Meaning of =~ in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I came across an example in the Ruby documentation and am confused about it's exact meaning. I am referring to `=~`. The sample below uses it, but I'm not sure what it's purpose over say `==` is.

```
a = %w{ a b c d e f }
a.select {|v| v =~ /[aeiou]/}   #=> ["a", "e"]
```

Comment: You might want to bookmark some documentation: http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-3D-7E

Comment: @muistooshort thank you. Here's Ruby 2.1.0 docs. I looked for 20 minutes on Google to find this without any luck.

Comment: @Mohamad: symbolhound.com is your friend: http://symbolhound.com/?q=ruby+%3D%7E

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if v =~ /[aeiou]/ # if this value matches this regex
if v == /[aeiou]/ # if this value IS this regex
```

See the difference?

Comment: Thanks. I had a hunch it might be because of the regex.

Answer (score 2):

It matches to a regular expression.