# Ruby: what is the '=~' operator

Tags: ruby, operators

I was wondering if anyone could explain what the `=~` operator does in Ruby. I have seen it a few times but am unable to find a proper explanation of it.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12992065/meaning-of-in-ruby

Comment: Hey meagar, do you know whats the name of the search engine that can search symbols like these? I used to know it but of course i forgot.

Comment: @Zippie http://symbolhound.com

Comment: Thank you, although i think its not the one i was looking for. Guess i could have also used google :)

Comment: @Zippie: You can go to http://ruby-doc.org/core and type the operator into the *Methods* search and you'll find it.

Comment: @Zippie Google "ruby operators", get exhaustive list. Notice **[ruby operator "=~" - Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5781362/ruby-operator)** is the 5th result. No symbols required. Also, if you don't `@user`, they won't see your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is used to match Regexes against strings:

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Regexp.html#method-i-3D-7E

It returns either a Integer value of the first occurrence in the string or if the expression doesn't match the String it returns `nil`.

Comment: Thanks for responding constructively instead of just making me feel bad for not finding it in my search